what does なんだ mean here?
I cant find a definitive definition for なんだ when used in a sentence such as じゃあなんでここなんだ　（Why are you here？)?
Is it the same as 何だ? This seems to only be used as an interjection and as a sentence ender.

If you are asking about なんだ at the end of the sentence, it's not 何だ. This (な)んだ is one of the ways of making a question using an explanatory-の. It's basically the same なんだ/なんです as in 彼は学生なんだ, except that it's used as a question.
The following sentences all mean "Then, why here?", but with different nuance.

じゃあなんでここなの? (informal)
じゃあなんでここなんですか? (polite)
じゃあなんでここなんだ? (masculine, and sometimes slightly accusatory)

Note that they all contain の/ん, which is important when making a question to seek clarification.
See also:

Is なの the casual form of んです or is んだ?


Thank you so much !
